# aplicacion con tres activities y me da error al declarar las activities en el AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

El error que me aparece es:
'c.example.musicoa.MainActivity2' no se puede asignar a 'android.app.Activity'

Y este es el Android Manifest

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity2"></activity>
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity3"></activity>
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: son activities, no fragments??

Comment: Escribo en respuestas porque aún no puedo realizar comentarios. Deberías de dar más información acerca de las Activities que estás mencionando, ya que la parte del código que muestras se ve bien por lo que hace falta más información. Ojalá puedas poner código de tus Activites para ver si realmente son Activities, si están bien construidas, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar pero me podrias decir en concreto que Activities tengo que poner porque he empezado con todo esto hace poco y todavia tengo que aprender mucho gracias.

Comment: Las que declaraste en tu Manifest: MainActivity2, MainActivity3 y MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

El problema que describes:

> El error que me aparece es: 'c.example.musicoa.MainActivity2' no se
>   puede asignar a 'android.app.Activity'

Se debe a que las Activity que defines dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` deben extender de `Activity`, `AppCompatActivity`, `FragmentActivity` o `ActionBarActivity` pero **NO debe extender de `Fragment`**.

Ejemplos:

---

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
```

---

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
```